# How to properly use lerna and webpack when dealing with a monorepo

Tags: javascript, webpack, lerna

I am structuring a monorepo that will contain all the single components of a UI kit built with React.

I am using [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) because I have no experience with monorepo/multi packages configuration, now I have this structure:

```
index.js
packages/
  pack1/
  pack2/
```

I want to build every package with `webpack` but want to use only a single `webpack.config.js` in the root folder and a single command to create a `pack*.dist.js` in every package directory.

Is it possible? Any direction?

Answer (score 10):

The question is rather general an open-ended, but here's a start.

> I want to build every package with webpack but want to use only a
>   single webpack.config.js in the root folder and a single command to
>   create a pack*.dist.js in every package directory.
>
> Is it possible? Any direction?

Yes, its possible. You need to list `pack1` and `pack2` as an `entry` in your `webpack.config.js` file. You probably want to bundle all common third party and in-house dependencies in a vendor bundle too.

With a webpack config such as:

```
let entries = {
  pack1: 'path/to/entry/point/pack1',
  pack2: 'path/to/entry/point/pack2'
};

export default {
  entry: { ...entries },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // ... usual rule config props
        include: [
          '/path/to/pack1/src-for-rule',
          '/path/to/pack2/src-for-rule'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        chunks: Object.keys(entries),
        minChunks: (module) => {
            return /node_modules/.test(module.context);
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'common',
        chunks: Object.keys(entries),
        minChunks: Object.keys(entries).length
    })
  ]
}
```

How you weave together the bundles into an "app" is up to you.

Comment: how would you define output for each pack?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an example repository showcasing a method for using lerna and webpack together here https://github.com/dan-kez/lerna-webpack-example

You can read more in the README but at a high level this repo seeks to show case the following:

- Monorepo code splitting via lerna
- Babel building across packages.
- A package with a webpack config that has dependencies on packages in
  the monorepo.
- Code splitting and asynchronous loading.
- Using "external" & code splitting to only load the code necessary
- A mix of TypeScript and Javascript packages (to show a transitional
  state)

Comment: OP asked for `a single webpack.config.js in the root folder and a single command to create a pack*.dist.js in every package directory`. Since your example does not do that, maybe you can expand on that a bit?